# Practical fast primality test

Tags: elementary-number-theory, math-software, primality-test

I want to test the primality of some numbers.
To do this I have tried PARI/GP and from the command line:

```
isprime(1797985968535216664944496004358374343509215681442061471412191560717902567100922783048272325884204171542595289833292525444657649015706240748603258905587228070218364321463272748372578381297752753873677472254922355241777152285815968419478586580462607181532633401390493324158696274873236811462980002924358959014961523858527582932580094707941486443910926176542073077556968436127272895058310597583607027726718736469175668307253909021323053371430188118304785898711275203434771737000724872573886880637420519724444463284443388727630283664666528052367541776313661585262983733024993681478681073098831498512514689575760815626512236554172414169581755726459092026691025970210757809328265617410698278014699792075882575574349505687630013946351950460669539772156003437151693004013771313802959350891175251984857136050528938291210156109810918641191927163139067163195482729770659833966232718210585298243545222708068057806276615307574921733035321516850527615134840300065761)
```

took about $90$ seconds to return $1$ (prime).

Are there options with PARI/GP or other software to make the computation faster, for numbers with $1000$ digits like the one above or even more?

**EDIT**

I have found a PARI/GP function `ispseudoprime` which is much faster and meets my needs for a first evaluation, i.e. I could run `isprime` only when `ispseudoprime` returns $1$.
Anyway it would be nice to know about other alternatives.

Comment: "ispseudoprime(n)" is very fast and very reliable. It takes only seconds for numbers with several thousand digits (although it cannot compete in speed with other , just faster , tools) and there is no known counterexample for the test. If you want to actually prove the primality , the best in PARI/GP is "isprime(n,2)" or "isprime(n,3)" which has a reasonable running time upto about 1 000 digits.

Comment: In the case that $n-1$ can esaily be factored , "isprime(n,1)" is very efficient !

Comment: Another alternative is Miller Rabin , "ispseudoprime(n,30)" , for example. Note that proving the primality of a huge random number is expensive.

Answer (score 3):

Mathematica returns the answer in milliseconds:

```
Timing[PrimeQ[179...761]]
{0.055672, True}
```

Comment: Do we know something about the used method, if heuristic or probabilistic test? Something else?

Comment: I would guess Miller Rabin is used.